CORS error in Mongo DB Atlas Data API call via Client side JS
I am trying to make an API call via Client side JS to Mongo DB Atlas API. Code snippet is as below.
            try {
            const exportData = await exportBackupData();
            const url = `https://${region}.data.mongodb-api.com/app/${appId}/endpoint/data/v1/action/insertOne`;
            const response = await fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    dataSource: 'mongodb-atlas',
                    database: dbName,
                    collection: collectionName,
                    document: exportData,
                }),
            });

I am getting the below error
{type: 'cors', url: 'https://ap-southeast-2.aws.data.mongodb-api.com/ap…ation-0-mbgslar/endpoint/data/v1/action/insertOne', redirected: false, status: 400, ok: false, …}

Gone through different links but all I get is CORS is now supported via Bearer Authentication and I am doing that.
I have added the hostname to the App settings -> Allowed Request Origins as well in mongodb.
Any idea what I am missing?

That's not a CORS error. type: 'cors' is just the default Fetch API mode value. A 400 response indicates a problem with your request content. What does the actual response text value say?

It's probably just because you're missing 'content-type': 'application/json' in your headers

@Phil - Adding Content-Type header solved it. Thank you!

See also the Response: type property. Logging out the raw Response object is rarely helpful
